# Ruby_Installation_Error_Watir

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems, watir, gemspecs

I'm running into the following error:

```
#ERROR
C:\Users\Farooq>D:

D:\>irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'

=> false

irb(main):002:0> require 'watir'

LoadError: cannot load such file -- watir/loader
        from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commonwatir-4.0.0/lib/watir.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
        from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from (irb):2
        from D:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0>
```

I have installed the gem `watir` and my system configurations are as follows:

- OS:Windows7
- IE:10

Comment: can you do `gem list --local` and show the output here?

Comment: D:\>gem list --local
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
bigdecimal (1.2.1, 1.1.0)
childprocess (0.3.9)
commonwatir(4.0.0)
ffi(1.9.0 x86-mingw32)
io-console(0.4.2, 0.3)
json(1.8.0, 1.5.5)
mini_portile(0.5.1)
minitest(5.0.8, 2.5.1)
multi_json(1.8.1)
rake(10.1.0, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc(4.0.1, 3.9.5)
rubyzip(1.0.0, 0.9.9)
selenium-webdriver (2.35.1)
watir-webdriver (0.6.4)
websocket(1.1.1, 1.0.7)
win32-api 1.5.0 universal-mingw32)
win32-process (0.7.3)
windows-api(0.4.2)
windows-pr(1.2.2)

Comment: @khan did you install watir gem correctly? if you are getting same error with firefox . try to install watir gem again .try gem install watir --system

Comment: @prashantsharma why `gem install watir --system` is needed.. please don't advice him this... Let him understand how to use `watir-webdriver`..

Comment: It worked for me with firefox.

Comment: hey prashanth can u tell me like how to access the element on gmail(account create page ) which has Birthday (month) it tried with all the valid html elements but unable t o identify it

Comment: please post new question for this . , I shall tell you then.

Comment: yaa i did that pleaase look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay! so looking at the output of `gem list --local` I can surely tell you that you installed [**`watir-webdriver`**](http://watirwebdriver.com/),not the **`watir`** gem.

You should write it as `require 'watir-webdriver'`. You also don't need to `require 'rubygems'`,as you are in Ruby1.9.3.

Here is a simple code using [**chrome**](http://watirwebdriver.com/chrome/):

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto 'https://www.google.co.in/'
b.text_field(:id => 'gbqfq').set 'ruby'
```

Comment: D:\>irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'watir-webdriver'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> ie=Watir::IE.start 'www.gmail.com'
NameError: uninitialized constant Watir::IE
        from (irb):2
        from D:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0>   when i do that iget the above error

Comment: @khan You are using `watir-webdriver` gem,not `watir`.. *Notice* that.

Comment: so wat next i mean i can open the browser through webdriver

Comment: browser=Watir::Browser.new :chrome   even i tried with the baive statements but i get the error can u please help me out

Comment: irb(main):004:0> browser=Watir::Browser.new :chrome
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: Unable to find the chromedriver exec
utable. Please download the server from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/do
wnloads/list and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at http://code.googl
e.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver.
from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:20:in `executable_path'
from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:33:in `default_service'

Comment: @khan do you have `firefox` ? Then try that.. for chrome and IE I think some extra installation you need to do..

Comment: @khan Did you try `b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox` ? It should work if you have installed `firefox`...

Comment: @khan did you install watir gem correctly? if you are getting same error with firefox . try to install watir gem again .try gem install watir --system

Comment: @prashantsharma OP wanted to use `watir-webdriver`.. Don't make him confuse with the new gem.. :) to use  `watir-webdriver`,`gem install watir-webdriver` enough..

Comment: thanks arup its working fine for firefox can u please tell me like what are the extra setings to be done for IE and CHROME

Comment: @khan I would suggest you to go with `Firefox`,as it is cool. But if you want chrome,then here you get the file to [download](http://watirwebdriver.com/chrome/).

Comment: one more question like without using watir-webdriver how can i navigate to browser using just Watir

Comment: hey arup how can u tell me like how to access the link in gmail(account create page),which contains BIRTHDAY(month)i tried with all the possible and valid html elements

Comment: hey can u please tell me how to accept the answer i started using it recently

Comment: hey done arup i have accepted by the way  what kind of benefit do u receive if i accept it ,do reply

Comment: k cool thats great hey can u tell which command is used to maximize the browser

Answer (score 6):

Make sure `watir` gem is installed correctly. You can do it like this:

```
gem install watir
```

Ignore the other answers here which say that you should not install `watir` - it is perfectly normal to install `watir` since this is a meta gem, which will load `watir-webdriver` or `watir-classic` as needed.

And then in your code, do like this:

```
require "watir"

b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome # loads watir-webdriver and opens up a Chrome browser
```

However, if you do not specify the browser, then default will be used for current platform.

```
# on Windows
b = Watir::Browser.new # loads watir-classic and opens up an IE browser

# on unix
b = Watir::Browser.new # loads watir-webdriver and opens up a Firefox browser
```

In other words - using a `watir` gem is perfectly normal even if you'd like to use `watir-webdriver` underneath it because you can switch the drivers really easily.

You can read more from the `watir` [readme](https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: when I say gem install watir I got the following error "unable to build native gem extension nmake is not recognized as internal or external command".

Answer (score 0):

got the same issue, what i did was clean all gems beside the default gem come with ruby by running "gem uninstall --all " and run "bundle install" using gemfile.